# coding values in DataFrame using table with interval description in python

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I have a table in pandas df1

```
id   value
1    1500
2    -1000
3    0   
4    50000  
5    50
```

also I have another table in dataframe df2, that contains upper boundaries of groups, so essentially every row represents an interval from the previous boundary to the current one (the first interval is "<0"):

```
group   upper
0       0
1       1000
2       NaN
```

How should I get the relevant groups for value from df, using intervals from df2? I can't use join, merge etc., because the rules for this join should be like "if value is between previous upper and current upper" and not "if value equals something". The only way that I've found is using predefined function with df.apply() (also there is a case of categorical values in it with interval_flag==False):

```
def values_to_group(x, interval_flag, groups_def):
    if interval_flag==True:
        for ind, gr in groups_def.sort_values(by='group').iterrows():
            if x<gr[1]:
                return gr[0]
            elif math.isnan(gr[1]) == True:
                return gr[0]
    else:
        for ind, gr in groups_def.sort_values(by='group').iterrows():
            if x in gr[1]:
                return gr[0]
```

Is there an easier/more optimal way to do it?

The expected output should be this:

```
id   value   group
1    1500    2
2    -1000   0
3    0       1
4    50000   2
5    50      1
```

Comment: what is your output dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with sorted `DataFrame` of `df2` by sorted `upper` and repalce last `NaN` to `np.inf`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'group':[0,1,2], 'upper':[0,1000,np.nan]})
df2 = df2.sort_values('upper')
df2['upper'] = df2['upper'].replace(np.nan, np.inf)
print (df2)
   group        upper
0      0     0.000000
1      1  1000.000000
2      2          inf

#added first bin -np.inf
bins = np.insert(df2['upper'].values, 0, -np.inf)
df1['group'] = pd.cut(df1['value'], bins=bins, labels=df2['group'], right=False)
print (df1)
   id  value group
0   1   1500     2
1   2  -1000     0
2   3      0     1
3   4  50000     2
4   5     50     1
```

Comment: well, for age we have the minimal value, but for something like ratio of changes in temperature to the previous temperature (doesn't matter what variable really), which can be negative or positive and doesn't have minimal and maximal values, we can't define the first bin (from - infinity to 0, for example). Also df2 has this row with nan value, that represents any age greater then 50, and it shouldn't be ignored. So cut() is not an option, I need something more versatile.

Comment: @Dmitriy - So can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: i've changed "age" to more abstract "value"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). Your only task is to construct `bins` and `names` input lists, which should be possible via an input dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [99, 53, 71, 84, 84]})
df['ratio'] = df['val']/ df['val'].shift() - 1

bins = [-np.inf, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, np.inf]
names = ['<0', '0.0-0.2', '0.2-0.4', '0.4-0.6', '0.6-0.8', '0.8-1.0', '>1']

d = dict(enumerate(names, 1))

df['Bucket'] = list(map(d.get, np.digitize(df['ratio'], bins)))

print(df)

   val     ratio   Bucket
0   99       NaN     None
1   53 -0.464646       <0
2   71  0.339623  0.2-0.4
3   84  0.183099  0.0-0.2
4   84  0.000000  0.0-0.2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there something like that for categorical values? In that case bins are defined by lists of values (like ['a', 'b', 'c']) and in case value is from some list then this bin's group should be associated with the value.

Comment: NumPy is low-level. It'll only ever map to integers directly. This is why we have to create a dictionary mapping integers to names.